# Fetching mysql query to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Is there any effective way to generate JSON out of MYSQL query like this?

```
SELECT * FROM player ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

because all I have found is this but for me it seems that there must be some easier way to get around:

```
function sql2json($query) {
    $data_sql = mysql_query($query) or die("'';//" . mysql_error());// If an error has occurred, 
            //    make the error a js comment so that a javascript error will NOT be invoked
    $json_str = ""; //Init the JSON string.

    if($total = mysql_num_rows($data_sql)) { //See if there is anything in the query
        $json_str .= "[\n";

        $row_count = 0;    
        while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_sql)) {
            if(count($data) > 1) $json_str .= "{\n";

            $count = 0;
            foreach($data as $key => $value) {
                //If it is an associative array we want it in the format of "key":"value"
                if(count($data) > 1) $json_str .= "\"$key\":\"$value\"";
                else $json_str .= "\"$value\"";

                //Make sure that the last item don't have a ',' (comma)
                $count++;
                if($count < count($data)) $json_str .= ",\n";
            }
            $row_count++;
            if(count($data) > 1) $json_str .= "}\n";

            //Make sure that the last item don't have a ',' (comma)
            if($row_count < $total) $json_str .= ",\n";
        }

        $json_str .= "]\n";
    }

    //Replace the '\n's - make it faster - but at the price of bad redability.
    $json_str = str_replace("\n","",$json_str); //Comment this out when you are debugging the script

    //Finally, output the data
    return $json_str;
```

Comment: Don't do this!!!! [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and `mysql_fetch_object()`!!!

Comment: To clarify: I mean don't attempt to manually construct JSON. Fetch your rows as objects, append them to an array, and json_encode() the whole thing.  4 lines of code.

Comment: ever heard of json_encode() function?

Comment: And use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)

Comment: Yes I know, thats why I've asked ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use `json_encode` on the object that comes back from `mysql_fetch_assoc`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 3):

Simply use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for array to json string convert.

For your example it will be something like this:

```
 ...
 $rows = array();
 while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_sql)) {
      $rows[] = $data;
 }
 echo json_encode($rows);
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `json_encode` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

- put the whole result into a php array, and `json_encode` the whole
- or if your result is huge,

  - first `echo '[';`
  - then echo each row independently encoded with `json_encode`
    (and don't forget to `echo ',';` when necessary)
  - finally close the json with `echo ']';`